# Adding multiple items to a list in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to coding in general and I am working in flutter right now. I've successfully been able to add single string objects into a list but I'm having issues adding an object with multiple strings into a list. I'd love some guidance if anyone's able to help!

This is my model

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

@JsonSerializable(anyMap: true, explicitToJson: true)
class Product {
  String productName;
  String productDescription;

  Product(this.productName, this.productDescription);

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    _$ProductFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ProductToJson(this);
}

Product _$ProductFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Product(
    json['product name'] as String,
    json['product description'] as String,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$ProductToJson(Product instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'product name': instance.productName,
      'product description': instance.productDescription,
    };

//trying to add Product strings into products
class UserData {
  ...
  final List<dynamic> accommodations; //successfully able to add single strings to list
  final List<dynamic> products; //unable to add multiple string objects to this list
  ...

  UserData(
      {...
      this.accommodations,
      this.products
      ...}
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"products": this.products};
}
```

Here is the database function to connect it to firestore

```
  Future addProduct(List products) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> productMap = {
      'products': products.map((product) => products.toList())
    };
    await userCollection.doc(uid).update(productMap);
  }
```

The await, which I've edited multiple times, either throws an error "ArgumentError (Invalid argument: Instance of 'Product')" OR "_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, Object>')"

Finally, here is the onPressed event which I'm trying to use to insert the two string values into the products list.

```
String _currentProductName;
String _currentProductDescription;
```

these are hooked up to textformfields

```
onChanged: (val) {
 setState(() => _currentProductName = val);
},
onChanged: (val) {
 setState(() => _currentProductDescription = val);
},
```

and the onPressed which I've also tried changing multiple times

```
RaisedButton(onPressed: () async {
 userData.products.add(Product(
  _currentProductName,
  _currentProductDescription));
 await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).addProduct(userData.products);
}),
```

Thank you!

Comment: What are the objectives of `addProduct` and `ButonPress`? They both do similar operations.

Answer (score 2):

1. When naming JSON params, use Snail Case:

   ```dart
   json['product_name'] as String,
   json['product_description'] as String,
   ```
2. Avoid dynamic as a List Type when you have already declared a Custom type because it can lead to unexpected behaviors in apps.

   Change

   ```dart
   final List<Product> products;
   ```

   to

   ```dart
   final List<dynamic> products;
   ```

   Now only `Product` type objects will be accepted into the `products` list.
3. When converting list items into JSON, you need to convert each item to JSON and add them to a list. For this you can use `map` function.

   Change

   ```dart
   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"products": this.products};
   ```

   to

   ```dart
   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"products": products.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList()};
   ```
4. Based on the code provided, I assume you want to add 1 Product (not multiple products at once) into the user object on the button press.

   ```dart
   Future<void> addProduct(Product product) async {
       // Add the product to the user's product list
       products.add(product); 

       // toJson() is the function to convert `User` object to a `Json Map`
       await userCollection.doc(uid).update(toJson()); 
   }
   ```

   Then the complete `User` class,

   ```dart
   class UserData {
     UserData({
       required this.accommodations,
       required this.products,
     });

     final List<dynamic>
         accommodations; //successfully able to add single strings to list

     final List<dynamic>
         products; //unable to add multiple string objects to this list

     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
         {"products": products.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList()};

     Future<void> addProduct(Product product) async {
       products.add(product);

       await userCollection.doc(uid).update(toJson());
     }
   }
   ```